# Conversion failed: Some directories do not have execute permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-lambda-layers

I am trying to create a **AWS Lambda Layer** in **AWS CloudFormation** but happens an error:

> Layer conversion failed: Some directories do not have execute permissions; (Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValueException; Request ID: eff63297-bf71-4578-a665-c493a9fbdb40)

Lambda Layer definition in CloudFormation Template:

```
LambdaLayerTest:
  Type: 'AWS::Lambda::LayerVersion'
  Properties:
    CompatibleRuntimes: 
      - nodejs8.10
    Content:
      S3Bucket: cf-us-west-2-test
      S3Key: LambdaLayerTest.zip
    Description: Lambda Layer Test
    LayerName: lambdalayertest
```

LambdaLayerTest.zip is a folder named "nodejs" with node_modules folder, package.json file and yarn.lock file.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "mylayertest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
     "aws-sdk": "2.307.0"
}
```

Comment: Could you please also provide the structure of LambdaLayerTest.zip and the minimal lambda layer code?

Also, the error message probably refers to some internal check and as it provides a request id, don't hesitate to contact AWS support to ask them for explanation. The template looks valid.

Comment: @Yann I Added. There is no code in my lambda layer. Only aws-sdk dependence,

Comment: Could you post a link to the `yarn.lock` as well?

Comment: I am not a JS guy, but looks like your runtime expects the structure of zip to be: `nodejs/node8/node_modules/` https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path

Comment: I got a similar error with SAM CLI v1.7.0. I uninstalled it and installed v1.6.2 (the previous version) and the error went away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file permissions in your zipped folder may be too restrictive for AWS Lambda:

[Permissions Policies on Lambda Deployment Packages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/deployment-package-v2.html#lambda-zip-package-permission-policies)

Running `chmod -R 755 <directory>` modifies read, write, and execute permissions recursively on all subdirectories and files.